# how to use 'if' and 'else' inside a variable

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code in which I am trying to use an if/else statement to assess if the returned string is empty; but, I have had no success so far.

```
$result = '<div class="card-deck">';

if($rows > 1) {
    while($list = $engrams->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result .= '
        <div class="col-4 p-2">
            <div class="card border-info m-1">
                <img src="/assets/images/items/'.$list['image'].'" alt="'.$list['name'].'" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-left: 60px; position: absolute; text-align: center;">
                    <p class="card-title">'.$list['name'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <p>'.$list['description'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name1'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name2'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name3'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <small><span class="text-left text-muted">Level Required: '.$list['lvl'].'</span></small>
                    'if (empty($list['engram_points'])) {'<small>PLM</small>'}'
                    'else {'<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>'}'
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
    }
}
$result .= '</div>';

echo json_encode(['result'=>$result,'rows'=>$rows,'qty'=>$qty,'active'=>$active])
```

Comment: You can't put if/else structures in the middle of a variable. Instead, look at [the ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above the Ternary operator is the way to go.

When used with your if else code it will look as follow:

```
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
    <small>
        <span class="text-left text-muted">Level Required: '.$list['lvl'].'</span> 
    </small>'
    . ( empty($list['engram_points']) ? '<small>PLM</small>' : '<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>' ) .
'</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
        <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
            <small><span class="text-left text-muted">Level Required: '.$list['lvl'].'</span></small>
            '.empty($list['engram_points']) ? '<small>PLM</small>' : '<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>'.'
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put code inside a string like this. You can, however, break the string and use if/else inside the loop... like this:

```
while($list = $engrams->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result .= '
        <div class="col-4 p-2">
            <div class="card border-info m-1">
                <img src="/assets/images/items/'.$list['image'].'" alt="'.$list['name'].'" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-left: 60px; position: absolute; text-align: center;">
                    <p class="card-title">'.$list['name'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <p>'.$list['description'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name1'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name2'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name3'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <small><span class="text-left text-muted">Level Required: '.$list['lvl'].'</span></small>';

                    if (empty($list['engram_points'])) {
                       $result .= '<small>PLM</small>';
                    }
                    else {
                       $result .= '<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>;
                    }

        $result .= '        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the variable is empty before assigning all the values to the `$result` variable.

Example:

```
if (empty($list['engram_points'])){
    $points = "<small>PLM</small>";
}else{
    $points = '<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>';
}

 $result .= '
        <div class="col-4 p-2">
            <div class="card border-info m-1">
                <img src="/assets/images/items/'.$list['image'].'" alt="'.$list['name'].'" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-left: 60px; position: absolute; text-align: center;">
                    <p class="card-title">'.$list['name'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <p>'.$list['description'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name1'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name2'].'</p>
                    <p>'.$list['res_name3'].'</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <small><span class="text-left text-muted">Level Required: '.$list['lvl'].'</span></small>
                   '.$points.'
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's ternary operator as follows:

```
$var='<small>'.($list['engram_points']?$list['engram_points']:'PLM').'<small>';
```

The format is (expr1 ? expr2 : expr3) and evaluates to - if expr1 is set then use expr2 else use expr3

Further info : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure, if you are *really* looking to put the logic in a variable:

```
<?php

function createLister($list) {
              return function() use ($list) {
                  // Your logic
                  if (empty($list['engram_points'])) {
                      return '<small>PLM</small>';
                  } else {
                      return '<small><span class="text-right text-muted">Skill Points: '.$list['engram_points'].'</span></small>';
                  }
              };
}

$lister = createLister($list);
echo $lister(); // Your output
```

See more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Otherwise the ternary operator might be what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$condition = true;

$doThis = 'Hello World';
$elseThis = 'Goodbye';

// Outputs 'Hello World'
$condition ? $doThis : $elseThis;
```